# iOS core data how to access single entity from different entities

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

I have a model like this:

[image]

How do I make it so that the "files" entity can be referenced by either Entity1 or Entity2 (or Items)

Basically I have a number of "files" with id's. If a change is made to a "file" (changed name for example), then when  any Entity references the file, it should have the updated info...without having to update in each entity.

Is there a way to do this from the editor? Or do I have to write the code to first get the file id i'm looking for, and then once I have the file id, do a separate request for the "File" entity using the id I just got?

In sql I could just do a left join from any table. If it's possible to do in a predicate, that would work too, just not sure how.

EDIT:

So I updated my model, now it looks like this:

[image]

I added data for a"File" and then added data for  Entity1 and Entity2

I have code that works to display Files, and then code that works that display the entities.
Here's a snippet of what I'm doing:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                          entityForName:@"Entity1" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

NSError *error;
NSArray *entityArray = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

[entityArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Entity1 *entity1, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"entity1: %@", entity1.name);
}];
```

How do I now get the 'name' from File for Entity1? Lets pretend the name field is a matching field. What do I need to add to the code to pull the "File"? This is assuming the "File" was there before the "Entity1" was there of course.

I'm currently running another method that looks something like: "getFileByName:(NSString *)name" and doing a separate request using a predicate. This works but I think there is a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by 'so that the "files" entity can be referenced by Entity1, Entity2 or Items' ?

Comment: I thought if I make a relationship to files from Entity1, then I wouldn't be able to access the same files from entity2. I will try Dan's answer and see if it works. Thanks for checking this out.

Comment: Your edit is another question altogether. consider reposting it as one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply create relationships to the `Files` entity for any other entity that like to reference them (with the cardinality you desire).

Remember, although the `Files`.`id` is unique, the uniqueness offered by CoreData is the `objectID` ==> you could substitute the `id` referencing with the file `objectID` and get the same functionality.

Some suggestions:

1. don't use `id` as a property name, it is a reserved word in Objective-C
2. don't name your entities in a plural form (ex. `Files` --> `File`) they are an object definition or class (don't think in terms of tables, although this might be the underlying structure)

Comment: So I can create a one to many relationship from entity1 to files, as well as a one to many relationship from entity2 to the same files entity i used in entity1? (I will try it anyway while waiting).. and thanks for the object id tip, issue here is the id's are getting pulled from an outside source and may be updated at some point, so that's my link back to the server data.

Comment: @Amos then change them to `identifier` in your code.  You **can't** use `id`. It is a reserved word and **will** cause you issues.

Comment: @Dan I'm trying out one->one relationships to the "files" entity and will see if that works...Thanks for the suggestions, This example much simpler than what I'm actually working with. Funny you brought up the "plural" name issue, I actually just finished changing all my entity names before coming back to check this post because it didn't 'look' right in the code. I do have a couple places with "id" so I will change those. thanks also marcus

Comment: In the model editor, I made a one to one relationship from entity1 to files, that worked fine. Then tried to do the same from entity2 to the same files entity, and it gives me a warning that files.entity1 should have an inverse. when I add the inverse, it removes it for files.entity2 and then I get the warning there. Will continue until I am able to get to the point where I can se data

Comment: @Amos For every entity referencing the `File` entity you need a new relationship, you cannot reuse the same link other entities use

Comment: @DanShelly Ah ok, so I can't have the same relationship *name* in two entities if they are both pointing to the "File" entity. Thanks, I think you understand what I'm attempting. I still don't have enough code yet to try this but when I do I will check back.

Comment: You should have Files.entity1, Files.entity2, Files.item, Entity1.file, Entity2.file, Item.file (or plural it they are to-many)

Comment: I updated my question to include all the good pointers you guys have been giving me... What do I need to add to make this work?

Comment: I will not add this to my answer as it is not relevant to the original question. Your way of matching the file to the entity is the way to do it in general, but you can optimise the performance of the fetching process. since its a one time operation, performance is not much of an issue.

Comment: Ok thanks and appreciate everyone's help.. at least I know now that I was moving in the right direction. This has helped me sort it out and get a better understanding so I will accept this as the answer.